# iterrows --> use first row as base

Tags: python, dataframe, openpyxl

Is there a way to use first row as base for compare with other rows in same column ?
Basically i would like to define, or better lock first row cell and then compare each next row with first one. The idea is to write result of compare in next column but in some order.

So i found that this can be done with openpyxl and something like this:

```
import openpyxl
fileName = "C:\testNumbers.xls"
my_wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(fileName)
my_sheet_obj = my_wb_obj.active
my_max_col = my_sheet_obj.max_column
for i in range(1, my_max_col + 1):
   cell_obj = my_sheet_obj.cell(row = 1, column = i)
   print(cell_obj.value, end = " ") # value of first row that should be used as base.
```

How can i now use this cell_obj.value ( cell 1 ) and compare is to all other cells in column ?
To better understand how this should look like, i have add a picture.
https://ibb.co/2jzXz5N

Second thing is that i need to understand how to use excel_writer and add the result to cells i second column...  Any ideas ?

Comment: Any reason for not using Pandas?

Comment: Create a set of the values and compare agains that? Easy enough.

Comment: No. I was just thinking that openpyxl would be better when dealing with cells... Can you share some code suggestion ?